# Нету беспроводного подключения

Tags: wifi

Помогите пожалуйста. Купил ноутбук Lenovo, с Windows 8. Проблема состоит в том, что не могу подключится к роутеру. Ноутбук видит сеть, но высвечивается восклицательный знак, секунду есть Интернет, потом пишет "Без подключения к Интернету". Уже перелазил все сайты, все службы поставил "автоматически подключать", отключил антивирус и браузер, провел диагностику, лазил в реестре...С роутером все нормально, поскольку на смартфоне и компьютере интернет работает исключительно. Уже не знаю, что делать. Если кто-то сталкивался с таким посоветуйте пожалуйста, как исправить. Заранее огромное спасибо.

Comment: Разбираться нужно. скорее всего роутер таки виноват

Comment: нужно проверять постепенно. Вначале проверить, выдало ли правильный ip. Если выдало, с консоли попинговать что то по айпи (например, телефон или другой комп). Потом попробовать попинговать внешний айпи, к примеру гугловый 8.8.8.8. И после этого попинговать что то по имени, к примеру ping yandex.ru. Если на каком-то этапе будут проблемы - пишите.

Comment: Проверьте св-ва подключения, ip-адрес должен быть из вашей подсети, шлюзом должен быть указан  ip-адрес вашего роутера.